# python selenium trying to press a link on a table

Tags: python, web

hi i'm new to python and selenium I'm trying to follow a link to an order page and the link is not clickable with selerium it's a clickable section on a web table

```
<a class="css-sywvol-text3-OrderCell" href="/orders/single-item/8wW8glWmWkaoNW_LrvZcsw">
```

this is the element I'm trying to click to follow the href link

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="tm-app-content"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a").click
```

Comment: What website and the .click should be .click().

Comment: I tried using click() still wouldn't work
i get this error 
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="tm-app-content"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Also using find elements so you should select the [0] to click or just use find element.

Comment: it's a eBay dropshipping monitor website there is an orders table and the section on the row showed in the screenshot is clickable leads to a page with the full details of the order I'm trying to follow the link 
https://snipboard.io/QJImiH.jpg

Comment: the first one answer worked now on the next page I have a collapse button:
<button class="css-191kab0-CollapseButton-text2-arrow-arrowCont-arrowDown-ItemInfo e5oip9z7">Show more</button> i tried the same thing : 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("css-191kab0-CollapseButton-text2-arrow-arrowCont-arrowDown-ItemInfo e5oip9z7").click()  but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your only finding one element to use find_element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-sywvol-text3-OrderCell").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="tm-app-content"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a").click()

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="tm-app-content"]/div/section[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a")[0].click()
```

Several ways you can do this. Use 1 or 2 if you only need a single tag clicked. 3 if you need a collection of similar web elements clicked.